# How to use ccxt methods like fetchticker, etc on user-defined variable, attribute?

Tags: python, trading, algorithmic-trading, ccxt

I am relatively new to Python and Software development in general.
I have made the following code, and my query at this stage is,
How do I connect to CCXT library using a user defined parameter or variable?
`

```
class Exchange:
    """ docstring goes here """
    def __init__(self, ex_name):
        self.name = ex_name
        ex_obj = getattr(ccxt, ex_name)
        self.ex = ex_obj({
            'enableRateLimit': True
        })
        print(self.ex)      # just for checking connection


Exchange('binance')
```

`How do I achieve THIS result?`

```
exchange = ccxt.binance()
print(exchange.fetch_ticker('BTC/BUSD'))
```

`

How do I get to use the ccxt methods on custom/ user-defined variables or attributes.

Comment: I may be too new to Python to understand what you are doing here but when I create the `exchange` object this is my code
```exchange = ccxt.kucoin({})```

additionally I pass in the exchange credentials.  So in the brackets above:

```({
        'password' : apiPassword,
        'apiKey': apiKey,
        'secret': apiSecret,
        'enableRateLimit' : True,
    })```

It's for Kucoin but should be similar enough.